# unable to upload cookbook from knife to chef-server

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, chef

I am running open source chef server on ubuntu ec2 instance. I am trying to upload the cookbook from my workstation using knife to chef-server, I am getting following error

```
home/jeevan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:66:in `timeout'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in `execute'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/resource.rb:76:in `put'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:151:in `block in uploader_function_for'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:25:in `call'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in setup_worker_threads'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:24:in `loop'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in setup_worker_threads'
```

when I ran the same command in the verbose mode I figured out knife or workstation or chef-client installed on my laptop is trying to connect to the private ip of the ubuntu ec2 instance.

How do I prevent the knife to stop connecting to private ip of the ubuntu ec2 instance and connect to the sub-domain/domain or elastic ip of the server.

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep using the URL of ec2 instance instead of private ip all the time because AWS will help you to resolve the right ip address.

Checkout the knife configuration file at `~/.chef/knife.rb`, make sure the value of entry `chef_server_url` composes of ec2 instance URL instead of ip address.